# Github HTTPS cloning via proxy

Tags: git, ssl, https, proxy, github

When trying to clone a github repository via a proxied connection, I get the following error:

```
Cannot get remote repository information.
Perhaps git-update-server-info needs to be run there?
```

I tried to set env variables http_proxy and https_proxy, I also tried to run

```
git --global my.proxy.com:port
```

but it still doesn't work.

Any idea ?

Comment: Where is the remote repository hosted?  Is `git-update-server-info` being run there? :)

Comment: The remote repository is hosted on github.com actually

Comment: Oops, I missed that in your question.  I suspect that your version of git is too old, and doesn't support Smart HTTP - what does `git --version` report?

Comment: I installed it via yum on my linux distro. Should I remove it and install manually a newer version ?

Comment: Hopefully your distribution should have a more recent version than 1.5.5.6 available for installation.  (That version is very old now.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that your version of git is too old - you need at least version 1.6.6 in order to use Smart HTTP.  I thought that GitHub would fall back to the dumb HTTP protocol if the client couldn't do Smart HTTP, but in any case, upgrading your version of git should eliminate a number of possible problems.

Comment: I just installed version 1.7.7.2 but now I get the following error: 
"fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'"
when trying to clone repo

Comment: I just installed curl-devel and rebuilt git. And it works :). Thank you, Mark.